# Tor relay on port 9001 TCP

Tags: tor, tcp, netstat

I executed `netstat -t` on my linux terminal and noticied a tor relay running on port 9001. I've search about the IP address of relay on shodan and got a result that address is from Russia, after that i have "googled" it and found some websites saying this can be a malware, a trojan or a spyware, nothing more. Can someone explain me what it can be? Is really a trojan or a spyware or is normal?

**OBS:** When i perform `netstat -t` any tor service or Tor Browser is running. I also run `sudo service tor stop` to confirm.

Comment: Run `netstat -natup` and see which process is actually bound to the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't run TOR yourself, it's probably a trojan. Some trojans connect over TOR to the CnC server. Most of them just execute the default TOR client and since most of them don't care to configure it properly, they start up the TOR relay too.

But if you are using TOR yourself, it's probably yourself who ran the relay service.

Answer (score 2):

To conclude that this is a "tor relay" is a stretch. Tor commonly uses port 9001, but that doesn't mean whatever *you're* running on port 9001 is actually tor related.

In my case I had a false positive that sounded tor related. But it wasn't. Here's the `nmap` output for one such host in my network. I've noted the incorrect assumptions.

```
Nmap scan report for my-docker-host-box (10.24.4.41)
Host is up (0.00053s latency).
Not shown: 995 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3000/tcp open  ppp        # Actually OpenSpeedTest HTTP
3001/tcp open  nessus     # Actually OpenSpeedTest HTTPS
5000/tcp open  upnp       # Actually Frigate's HTTP WebUI
9001/tcp open  tor-orport # Actually Portainer Agent daemon
MAC Address: 00:61:0C:29:1D:ED (VMware)
```

The situation described in the question certainly warrants further investigation, but isn't conclusive evidence of anything malicious.